# jQuery update variable on AJAX success

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have the following jQuery function which works:

```js
var userid = $('.userid').val();

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  var formidlength = $('.formid').val();
  if (formidlength.length < 1) {
    //New Questionnaire
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
      data: {
        action: 'save',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        form_user: userid,
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $(".success").html(data);
        $('.formid').val(data);
      }
    });
  }
}, 600);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <input type="hidden" class="formid" name="formid" value="">
  <input type="hidden" class="userid" name="userid" value="1">
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <form method="post" class="new">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The basic gist of my function is it will auto save a form every X seconds, on the first save it creates the form in the database and passes back the ID to the formid field, on every other save it will just update the fields for the form by using the ID.

My issue is the `if( formidlength.length < 1 ) {` doesn't run again so the function just keeps creating a new form.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to create an autosave feature you should not be making an AJAX request every 0.6s. That will just DDOS your own server. Instead hook a timeout to an event such as `input` so that progress is saved after a specific delay with no user interaction, such as 30 seconds. In addition you can have a timer which saves regardless of user input at a larger delay, say every 5 minutes.

Comment: Also note that your statement that the `if` condition doesn't run again is false, it runs every 600ms. If the condition isn't being hit, then your DOM is not in the state you believe it to be. Without seeing a working demo, or even any HTML, we can't really help you debug this.

Comment: @rory I set the time to that just to test, it will be every 5 minutes in the actual live website. I will add the html now.

Comment: your code just doesnt make sense to me, you should probably debug the contents of 'formidlength' and the part about updating the already created form is not included at all, i would rather just check on server side if id is provided or not and create or update accordingly